# Import Bulk of Records from Excel File to SQLite using Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any possible to insert bulk of records from MS-Excel file to Sqlite Database     using Android.If anybody can so please give a sample code here.. Because i have around 1100 records in Excel and i have to use those records in my app. Can anyone help me to save my time...

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can't you convert excel to csv? (like in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wx9yNU_1lvg)  It's not impossible to read excel files directly but it's a big pain compared to a simple text based format - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210983/how-to-read-xls-file-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I got some idea to work on it..

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a OleDB provider for Sqllite, then connecting to the database you could use ADO (old school), or you could use a COM+ dll which you could activate via CreateObject() a good place to start is http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers and one ive actually used before http://dimzon541.narod.ru/sqlitex/

#### you can also use http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com/

may be you can convert excel file into JSON and then using JSON parse you can re-entered data in to sqlite